# Cannot declare a variable with public access in a class from a module

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am making a GUI based application (forms), and encountered the following error.

Firstly, I am declaring the following stuff in a module

```
Module test_mod

    Public Structure sub_struct
        Public test_int() As Integer
        Public Sub foo()
            ReDim test_int(3)
        End Sub
    End Structure

    Public Structure main_struct
        Public test_aaa As sub_struct
    End Structure

End Module
```

Of course, my real code is longer and more complicated than this, but this piece of code will be a perfect example.

Then I declare this `test_mod` in the main class

```
Public Class Form1
    Public test_this_struct As New test_mod.main_struct
    'do something here
End class
```

My intention is making the `test_this_struct` accessible by other modules (which are not shown here), such that the main class will be short and tidy. However, it keeps complaining the following:
`test_this_struct` cannot expose type `test_mod.main_struct`outside the project through class `form1`.

I do not see any `Private` here, and I tired to remove the `new`, `redim`, and "struct in struct", but they did not work.

I found an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90htzsex.aspx) and its related content on MSDN, but it did not really help me.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Module test_mod
    Public Structure sub_struct
        Public test_int() As Integer

        Public Sub foo()
            ReDim test_int(3)
        End Sub
    End Structure

    Public Structure main_struct
        Public test_aaa As sub_struct
    End Structure
End Module
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aaxss7da.aspx

Answer (score 3):

By default [modules and classes are `Friend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235296%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) (only visible to your assembly).

Your form, however, is explicitly `Public`, which exposes it and its members to the world - which extends `test_mod.main_struct`'s visibility.

Declare your module as `Public` too.