# Structure defined in VB Module cannot be recognized in VB Class

Tags: vb.net

I defined structure called USIM_DEF in Module Telephony.

Module Telephony is located in file common.vb
From another file BatteryTests.vb from Function F1 I call function F2 that is defined in file BaseStationClass.vb in Public Class BaseStation. 
Function F2 has one of the parameters the structure USIM_DEF. The error that I get is:

'USIM_DEF_elem' cannot expose type 'Telephony.USIM_DEF' outside the project through class 'BaseStation'.    C:\Git\Power_Automation\Power_Automation\bin\tests\tests\BaseStationClass.vb    106 48  tests

This is my code please help:

File common.vb

```
Module Telephony

    Public Structure USIM_DEF
        Public SimIndex As USIM_ind
        Public Rat As CELL_RAT
        Public PlmnNum As PlmnNumberParts
    End Structure
```

File BatteryTests.vb

```
Module BatteryTests
    Sub Prepare_UE(.,.,.,.,.,)
        'I call function that defined in file
    End Sub
```

File BaseStationClass.vb

```
Public Class BaseStation
    Overridable Function SetMNC(ByVal device As GPIB,
                        ByVal USIM_DEF_elem As USIM_DEF,  //compile ERROR  
                        Optional ByVal container As TestContainer = Nothing,
                        Optional ByVal timeout As Integer = 1000) As Boolean
        Return False
    End Function

    Overrides Function SetMNC(ByVal device As GPIB,
                        ByVal USIM_DEF_elem As USIM_DEF,  // compile ERROR                                                       
                        Optional ByVal container As TestContainer = Nothing,
                        Optional ByVal timeout As Integer = 1000) As Boolean
        ' .......
        ' ......
        ' ......
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

What is wrong
Why I cannot call in Public Class the parameter of structure type that defined in Module ????

Thanks a lot
Ilana

Comment: You need to declare your Telephony Module as Public if you want the structure to be useable in a Public Function. `Public Module Telephony`

Comment: Blackwood, million of thanks for your simple but helpful advise

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot declare a variable with public access in a class from a module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898462/cannot-declare-a-variable-with-public-access-in-a-class-from-a-module)